# netflix hystrix and spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration, hystrix, netflix

I have a spring integration project that sends data to various sources via gateway and also fetching data from databases and updating certain tables.

It is working fine just there are so many points of failure and wish I could wrap the calls to these gateways with Netflix's Hystrix framework and have it displayed the Hystrix DashBoard.

All Ideas and Suggestions are welcomed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the info you need in the Hystrix GitHub repo page [here](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix).
Documentation regarding the dashboard is found in the same place, but in the master branch [here](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/tree/master/hystrix-dashboard)

There are several ways to use the framework, but most commonly, you would wrap your service/call inside a `HystrixCommand` object, and fill the `run()` and `fallback()` methods. You can find an example [here](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix#hello-world)

Regarding the dashboard, you need to build the project and you can use it "out of the box"; that is if you don't want to go deep into its configuration. You will then be able to access it through your web explorer, and trace the calls from the service(s) that are wrapped up with Hystrix, by entering their URL in the dashboard homepage.
You can find additional documentation about the dashboard in the Hystrix [wiki](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Dashboard).